# Native messaging, re: re-establishing a connection with host application after close

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a functioning extension that communicates with native host C# app. Looking for a way to automatically re-establish a connection with the C# app after I close and re-open it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure : you want the client app (chrome extension) to reconnect to the host app (C# app) when you close and reopen the C# app ?

Comment: How often does your extension tries to communicates with your host app ?

Comment: The connection is established when the extension is loaded; after that it listens for text from the host app (c#). The issue is that once the c# app is closed, chrome automatically begins listening on another port. That is, the c# app is continuing to attempt to write to the original port, but chrome appears to create another port to listen on. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So you won't get something like a timeout ?
In that case can you from the extensions ask the host if it is still here (i.e. once every 30 seconds) and if you get no answer, drop the old connection and create a new one ?

Comment: Sidewinder: good idea, i'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Native messaging means only Chrome can start a host instance when it "connects". It's a misnomer, since `connect()` means "launch a new copy and talk to it".

There is no way to "attach" to an already-running process. If you close the host, stdio pipe is broken the `Port` object fires `onDisconnect` event. Then you need to re-launch the host from the extension to be able to talk to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about asking the server if it's still here (i.e. once every 30 seconds)

if you get no answer given a certain delay (=> timeout) drop the connection and create a new one.

Th delay must not be too fast, to avoid resettong connections when there is only a 'lag spike'