# A custom extension is not listed in extensions page in some computers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have developed a Google Extension for which I created a Windows installer package. That installer writes the corresponding registry entries as explained in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry

All that works well in some computers. So, after I run the installer package and then run Google Chrome, a little popup appears telling me to enable the extension. I answer “Yes” to that question and from that time on, the extension works as expected.

However, in some computers, with the same version of Chrome (53.0.2785.116 m), the installer writes the corresponding entries to the registry but when I run Chrome, nothing happens and the extension is not listed in the chrome://extensions/ page.

In such cases, I can connect to web store to install the extension manually. However, this extension launches an application because it implements Native Messaging. When I install the extension manually it works (the native messaging host application is launched and works) but when I close and re-open  Chrome, the host application is not run. To run it, I need to manually disable and then re-enable the extension.

Very strange what happening. Can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705852/native-messaging-re-re-establishing-a-connection-with-host-application-after-c), (which is somewhat related to your issue), when you close the Chrome, it will fire `onDisconnect` event that's why the application is not running.

> Native messaging means only Chrome can start a host instance when it "connects". It's a misnomer, since `connect()` means "launch a new copy and talk to it".
>
> There is no way to "attach" to an already-running process. If you close the host, stdio pipe is broken the `Port` object fires `onDisconnect` event. Then you need to re-launch the host from the extension to be able to talk to it.

You can check on this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/120743/how-to-install-extensions-from-outside-the-chrome-web-store/). Just make sure that no antivirus or firewall programs on your computer are causing the problem. If you can open Google Chrome when the firewall is off, you may need to [create an exception](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Nep7hbCXqmQ) in your antivirus or firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

> However, in some computers, with the same version of Chrome (53.0.2785.116 m), the installer writes the corresponding entries to the registry but when I run Chrome, nothing happens and the extension is not listed in the chrome://extensions/ page.

You may be encountering [blacklisting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#faq) if that extension was ever installed, then uninstalled.

> **What if the user uninstalls the extension?**
>
> If the user uninstalls the extension through the UI, it will no longer
>   be installed or updated on each startup. In other words, the external
>   extension is blacklisted.
>
> **How do I get off the blacklist?**
>
> If the user uninstalls your extension, you should respect that
>   decision. However, if you (the developer) accidentally uninstalled
>   your extension through the UI, you can remove the blacklist tag by
>   installing the extension normally through the UI, and then
>   uninstalling it.